# Window.Show() Not Showing Windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a slight issue creating a new window. The weird part is that the window seems to be created, but calling `.Show()` or `.Activate()` does nothing.

The code I'm using to create the window is:

```
TicketView tv = new TicketView();
tv.Activate();
```

I was originally trying to set the data context of the window at the same time, but I've taken that out to see if it was the issue, but I'm still seeing the same behaviour. Regardless, that's what the code is at this time. If anybody has any ideas, I'd be very grateful!

For reference - This is the ticket view XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Helpdesk.View.TicketView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TicketView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have a window named Window1 and this code works for me  `Window1 w = new Window1(); w.Show();`

Comment: From where do you call `Show()`? What do you do after calling it? And what does your application do? Does it exit? Something else?

Comment: @Haris I tried doing that, and it still just doesn't show. This is across 2 PC's as well.

@svick I'm currently calling it from a double click event handler in the code behind of the parent window, which simple runs the code posted above. I tried both `.Show()` and `.Activate()`, but neither works.

Comment: Are you sure you are creating the window on the UI thread?

Comment: I believe I am, yes. I'll double check that though, as it sounds like that could well be the issue.

Comment: Are you doing this after another window is shown? Do you want to show this window after another one is closed?

Comment: maybe it is created in a weird location for some reason. You may try specifying startup location and see if it does anything?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do. What I have done in the past if it is my main window is to use the [Application.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) method. If I am trying to run another window from my application I use the [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method.

Comment: I tried `.ShowDialog()` too, that just stops me clicking anything on the main window. It does tell me that my window is being created, but it still doesn't appear.

Comment: have you tried checking to make sure the visibility has been set?

Comment: I have. I tried setting `Visibility = Visible` before calling the `.Show()` method

Comment: The other question is what are the forms screen coordinates?

Comment: Try setting the owner to the parent form and then tell the secondary form to startup as centerowner

Comment: Agree with Mark, either your TicketView has to be the Main Window of the application or should have a parent window specified.

Comment: I'll try setting the parent window and see if that makes the difference